Given arrays A & B and an element-wise distance function f between them, minimize the sum of f over A & B by reordering B?
I have a problem I think I've managed to distill down to the following problem:
Given two arrays $A$ and $B$ of length $n$ and a pair-wise distance function $f(a_i, b_i)$, where $a_i \in A$ and $b_i \in B$, reorder the elements in $B$ to minimize
$$
\sum_i{f(a_i,b_i)}
$$
In my case $f$ is a distance function on strings (the ROUGE metric to be exact) and as far as I can figure out it doesn't have a useful substructure (e.g., it isn't monotonic) that could lend itself well to, e.g., dynamic programming.
A worst case solution would take $O(n!)$ time by trying all permutations of $B$ (after computing a distance metric lookup table for $f$ in $O(n^2)$ time).

Maybe this is an example of the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem?

This is indeed an instance of the assignment problem, as you speculated.  There is one left-vertex per element of $A$, and one right-vertex per element of $B$, and the weight of the edge between vertices $a_i,b_i$ is given by $f(a_i,b_i)$.  You are looking for a perfect matching of minimum weight, which can by solved by any algorithm for the assignment problem.  In particular, the problem can be solved in polynomial time.
